# Unable to load cookbooks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm following Amazon's [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cookbooks-101-opsworks-install-software-feature.html) for installing IIS on AWS using Chef.

The problem is that when I execute the custom cookbook I see the following:

```
# Logfile created on 2016-03-31 01:32:10 +0000 by logger.rb/41954 
[2016-03-31T01:32:10+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at http://localhost:8889 with repository at C:/chef 
One version per cookbook 
data_bags at C:/chef/runs/3011e6d2-9695-4cc2-97d0-b509c34c0b64/data_bags 
nodes at C:/chef/runs/3011e6d2-9695-4cc2-97d0-b509c34c0b64/nodes 

[2016-03-31T01:32:15+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.2.1 *** 
[2016-03-31T01:32:15+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2584 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to [] from CLI options 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Run List is [] 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [] 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for iis-app-server 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete. 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found : Object not found: /reports/nodes/iis-app-server/runs 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [] 
[2016-03-31T01:32:48+00:00] WARN: Node iis-app-server has an empty run list. 
[2016-03-31T01:32:49+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.218745 seconds 
[2016-03-31T01:32:49+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers 
[2016-03-31T01:32:49+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
```

It's unable to load the cookbooks for some reason.

Comment: what command are you executing?

Comment: I'm going to retag this for OpsWorks as any answer is not going to be relevant to Chef as a whole.

Comment: I am executing update_custom_cookbooks command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log you shown is the second Chef run, which should be empty for update_custom_cookbooks command. If you check the log, the update custom cookbooks should be in the first chef run at the top of your log.